# On enter key press, move the text to new input box

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events, keyboard-events

I have a complex requirement

> Detect the `keypress` of `ENTER` key inside a text box based on these conditions:
>
> 1. If the cursor is at the end of the sentence, it should add a new text box at the next row.
> 2. If the cursor is at the middle of the sentence, it should move the text from its position till end of the sentence to the new input box at the next row.

I'm being able to add a new input field to the next row like this:

```
if $event.keyCode == ENTER_KEY  //13
  newRow = initializeNewRowObject()
  $scope.list.splice(index, 0, newRow)
  setFocusOnNewRow(index)
```

Any idea how to achieve the purpose?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure creating a new text box is the best solution for the features you want to have and a rich text editor is what you've just described.

There are a few good ones out there - one that springs to mind is [DraftJS](https://facebook.github.io/draft-js/) but there are other non-react alternatives -- See [Redactor](https://imperavi.com/redactor/)